# Select jquery input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

It's a quick question for you,

I need to select Jquery element by type AND by name.

I know that we can do something like:

```
$('.form-control input[type=text]')....
```

but I need to select by name too..

do you have another way to do that unless using:

```
$('.form-control input[type=text]').each(function (){
   if($(this).attr('name') == 'search'){
        // this is my selector
   }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [**Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

```
$('.form-control input[type=text][name="search"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
$('.form-control input[type=text][name="search"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$('.form-control input[type=text][name="search"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$('.form-control input[type=text][name="search"]').each(function (){
  //ohh yeah....this is my selector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.form-control input[type=\'text\']')` 
or by name you can go

```
$('.form-control input[name=\'search\']')
```